# Unity Application.targetFrameRate problem

Tags: unity-game-engine

I write to my code "Application.targetFrameRate = 60;" and i have get 60FPS at Unity. But i play game on my phone with 120FPS. How can i fix it? I use the same way in a different game and it works.
FPS Display Code :

```
public class FPSDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int frame;
    public static float fpsTimer = 0f;
    public static float pollingTime = 1f;
    public Text fpsText;
    void Update()
    {
        fpsTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        frame++;
        if (fpsTimer >= pollingTime)
        {
            int frameRate = Mathf.RoundToInt(frame / fpsTimer);
            fpsText.text = frameRate.ToString() + " FPS";
            fpsTimer -= pollingTime;
            frame = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As per unity documentation. Update can run more than once per frame

Comment: @BugFinder O_o can you provide a link to this? `FixedUpdate` can easily be called many times per frame, but as far as I know there will be always only one `Update` call per frame

Answer (score 0):

I upgrade Unity version 2020 to 2021 and problem solved. I think 2020 version has more complicated Vsync settings.